# Global import for testing react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

If I wanted to do this in all my test.js files:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
```

Is there a way to globally import it so that every 'tests.js' file will automatically have that imported?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***globals!***](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html)

### Example:

#### setup.js

```
import { _shallow } from 'enzyme'
import _MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'
global.shallow = _shallow
global.MockAdapter = _MockAdapter
```

#### test1.js

```
describe('My Test 1', _ => {
  MockAdapter() // Use it!
})
```

### Notes:

Global variables will solve this particular issue. But the caveat is that you will have one instance across each test (*which might be ok depending on the dependencies you import*)

---

## EDIT: In context of [react-boiler-plate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate)

- If you read [***package.json***](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json), you'll see that there is a test setup file within [***`"jest"`***](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json#L186).
- This path is [*`react-boilerplate/internals/testing/test-bundler.js`*](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/internals/testing/test-bundler.js).
- Edit that file with the contents of ***setup.js*** (*aforementioned*)
- Now each one of your tests should have the variables defined

Comment: I tried that, my test.js file still says 'shallow' is undefined.

Comment: Did you make sure to run/import main.js before all your other tests?

Comment: How do you run/import main.js before all the test are run?

Comment: I'd be able to help more, if you gave an example of your directory structure, and what sequence are the files being imported/run in. Maybe include a snippet of the *`for loop`*

Comment: hi @AP, I just cloned the react-boiler-plate project, and created a file called globals.js in /utils directory and added the lines that you supplied and used it in another test.js file and it did not work. My ide is still telling me that the variable is undefined. Thanks!

Comment: Here, I fixed with edits topical to react-boiler-plate

Comment: Ok ... I've added the following to test-bundler.js

import { _shallow } from 'enzyme';
global.shallow = _shallow;


and in my test.js I removed import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
and my ide is still telling me 'shallow is undefined'.